# How to update from Chef 12.0.3 to 12.4

Tags: chef-infra

I want to update my Chef Server from 12.0.3 to 12.4 . I didn't find any documentation for this. What is the best procedure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the normal install procedure: https://docs.chef.io/upgrade_server.html#from-chef-server-title-12

Basically you stop it, install the new package, run `chef-server-ctl upgrade`, and then start it again.